# Raster calculator not giving correct output

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

I've been using the raster calculator and everything was working fine until I started getting unusual outputs:

[image]

Nothing shows up on the map and it took barely any time to calculate. This happened before and I re ran the calculator and I got a more sensible output, but re running the calculation no longer solves the problem. This is occuring on multiple tile calculations. How do I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried to stretch a histogram?

Comment: No I haven't, on these ones there is nothing to stretch

Comment: Show the formula that you used.